# one finger image scaling / Cropping

Tags: ios, imageview, gesture, image-scaling

I'm trying to implement one finger image scaling/Croping on iOS. 
Similar to Kirby Turner's one finger rotation. 
I'm looking for existing libraries or if you can help me with the code itself, it'll be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by one finger cropping, but I made this library for iOS cropping. Maybe it can help. https://github.com/nicholjs/BFCropInterface

Comment: Thanks. It sure gives me some ideas. I'll have to play around with it though. My photo editing is pretty complicated. It has rotation and several filters in same VC.